# If $\int{\frac{4e^x + 6e^{-x}}{9e^x - 4e^{-x}}}dx = Ax + B\log{(9e^{2x}-4)} + C$, then find A, B and C.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The answer to this question at the back of the book(from where I'm learning Integral Calculus) is given as:$ A = \frac{-3}{2}; B = \frac{35}{36}; C = \frac{-3}{2}\log{3}$

Here is my attempt at this problem:
[image: First part]

[image: Second part]

Is my solution wrong or is C really equal to $ \frac{-3}{2}\log{3} $ somehow?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a small mistake.
$$-\dfrac34\ln|z + 4| = -\dfrac34\ln|9e^{2x}| = -\dfrac34\left[\ln|e^{2x}| + \ln|9|\right] = -\dfrac32x - \dfrac32\ln3$$
From above, $C = - \dfrac32\ln3$.

Comment: To me, $C$ could be anything (absorbed in the integration constant) but you result is correct $C= - \dfrac32\ln3+K$.

Comment: Ahh! I hate arithmetic mistakes! Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a side comment.*

To compute  $A$ and $B$, we can avoid integration using
$$\int{\frac{4e^x + 6e^{-x}}{9e^x - 4e^{-x}}}\,dx = Ax + B\log{(9e^{2x}-4)} + C$$ Differentiating both sides,
$$\frac{4e^{2x} + 6}{9e^{2x} - 4}=A+\frac{18  e^{2 x}}{9 e^{2 x}-4}B$$ Let $e^{2x}=t$ to get 
$$\frac{4t + 6}{9t - 4}=A+\frac{18  t}{9 t-4}B$$ Make $t=0$ to get $A=-\frac 32$; now, make $t=1$ to get $2=A+\frac {18}5 B \implies B=\frac {35}{36}$